# Form results not displaying - D7

Tags: 7, forms, search

Below is my code. Form results are not displaying below the form. What am I missing ?

When I use `print_r($form_state['storage']['results']);` I'm getting the results.

But it is not displaying in the form.

Any ideas/suggestions will be helful.

```
function file_search_form($form,&$form_state) {
  $otpions = _get_country_titles();
  $form['countries'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Country'),
    '#options' => $otpions,
    '#required' => TRUE,

  );
  $form['entities'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Entity'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
  );

  if(isset($form_state['storage']['results'])) {
    $form['result'] = array
    (
      '#value' => t('The results of the form are: !results', array('results' => $form_state['storage']['results'])),
    );
  }

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => 'Search',
    '#type' => 'submit',
  );

  $form['#submit'][] = 'webform_options_submit';
  return $form;

}

function webform_options_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  $args = array(':entities' => '%'.$_REQUEST['entities'].'%', ':countries'=>$_REQUEST['countries']);
  $result = db_query("SELECT field_entity_value,field_country_value, filename
                   FROM field_data_field_entity,field_data_field_country , field_revision_field_file_upload, file_managed
                   WHERE ( field_data_field_entity.field_entity_value LIKE :entities
                   AND field_data_field_country.field_country_value= :countries )
                   AND field_data_field_entity.entity_id = field_revision_field_file_upload.entity_id
                   AND field_data_field_country.entity_id= field_data_field_entity.entity_id
                   AND field_revision_field_file_upload.field_file_upload_fid=file_managed.fid",$args );   
  foreach( $result as $item) {    
    $form_state['storage']['results'] = $item->filename;
  }
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added type markup below the submit code in $form_state['storage']['results'] and that does the trick...

```
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => 'Search',
    '#type' => 'submit',
  );

if(isset($form_state['storage']['results'])) {
        $form['result'] = array
        (
          '#type' => 'markup',
          '#markup' => t('The results of the form are: !results', array('results' => $form_state['storage']['results'])),
        );
      }
```